# ERROR on npm install command

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to nodejs and i am trying to use that with visual studio code editor. I am unable to install any packages. Getting this below error. I think its something to deal with proxy.

I have tried couple of solutions provided (e.g. changes the npm config etc) over the web but nothing seems to working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are behind a proxy it wont work you out.use this code

```
npm config set proxy http://myproxyblabla:myport
```

Comment: its not working either.
do we need to change anything in this code

Comment: Try 

`npm config set proxy http://<proxy-url>:<port>
and
npm config set https-proxy http://<proxy-url>:<port>`